# Extracting elevation from a TIN file with a point shapefile overlay

Tags: arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing, geometry

I have a TIN file that was built off of contour polyline shapefile (I think).  I have a point shapefile with a few points.

How can I extract elevation of the TIN file where the points occur?  I am using ArcMap with python automation.  Any free software would be welcome as well.  Perhaps a transforming of the TIN to another file type is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using ArcGIS 10 and 3D Analyst:

**Step 1:** ****Interpolate Shape tool**** (ArcToolbox-->3D Analyst Tools --> Functional Surface --> Interpolate Shape)  This will create a 3D Feature class/Shapfile from the 2D shapefile and the TIN input surface.

**Step 2:** ****Add XY Coordinates tool****  This tool will also add a Z coordinate if the feature class is 3D.  (ArcToolbox --> Data Management Tools --> Features --> Add XY Coordinates)

If this is something you do often you can automate this with Model Builder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it in ArcMap, but options are FME (drape transformer), but it's commercial. Another one is GRASS (or qgis with grass extension).