# How to extrude polygon features from a TIN surface in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

How do I Extrude polygon feature class from a TIN surface using ArcScene 10.1?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add polygon feature class to ArcSceene
2. To **drap your polygon features on a TIN surface** you have to [set base heights](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_a_feature_layer_s_base_height_from_a_surface/00q800000058000000/) for polygon feature class: Open Layer Properties of polygon feature class. Go to Base Heights tab. Use Floating on a custom surface option and chose your TIN here.
3. **Extrude you polygons** by [attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extruding_features_by_an_attribute_value/00q8000000vt000000/) or by [constant value](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Extruding_features_by_a_constant_value/00q80000002m000000/): Open Layer Properties of polygon layer. Go to Extrusion tab.

Answer (score 0):

From another post ([Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22120/extracting-elevation-from-a-tin-file-with-a-point-shapefile-overlay))

[Interpolate Shape](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000006m000000) Should do what you are looking for.

Comment: If I have understood the question correctly: Extraction of z-values from a TIN for a feature class is not what the OP wants. He wants to [extrude](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_using_extrusion_as_3D_symbology/00q80000009t000000/) polygons.

Comment: Interpolate Shape does extrude the polygons to the TIN. I believe what he wanted was making the shape 3d based off the elevation. (Step 2 of your answer) Your link extrudes to other values not the elevation. Without more details or response from the OP we will never really know what he wanted though.